# Closed form solution to this constrained optimization?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-programming

Given $w \in \mathbb R^{M}$ and symmetric positive semidefinite matrix $B \in \mathbb R^{M \times M}$, find $x \in \mathbb R^{M}$ such that

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & (x-w)^{T}B(x-w)\\ \text{subject to} & \|x\|_{1} \leq 1\end{array}$$

I was thinking if it's possible to break the problem into two parts, thus if I already can perform projection onto the $\ell_1$ unit ball efficiently, then would it be possible to solve for unconstrained problem of minimizing $(x-w)^{T}B(x-w)$, and if the $\ell_1$ norm of $x$ turns out to be greater than $1$, then I can perform the efficient projection of $x$ onto the $\ell_1$ unit ball, via

$$\arg\min {1 \over 2} \|x - y\|_2^2$$ given $$\|y\|_{1} \leq 1$$

Comment: I don't think your two-step argument works. Consider the instance with $W = [0.6; 0.6]$ and $B = [2, -3; -3; 5]$. The solution for the unconstrained version is clearly $X = W$, and the projection of $W$ on to the set $\left\{ z : \left\lVert z \right\rVert_1 \leq 1 \right\}$ is $[0.5; 0.5]$; however, the solution of the original optimization problem is $\left[\frac{31}{65}; \frac{34}{65}\right]$.

Comment: True. But I think nonetheless it could be a good starting point instead of starting at a random point within the L1 unit ball. So in that case, you'd start at [0.5;0.5] and perform projected gradient descent and reach [31/65;34/65] much quicker